# Need help to solve unexpected behaviour of CustomClipper and ClipPath in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm trying to make an hole in one layer of stack using custom clipper.
my CustomClipper class is,

```dart
class Clipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path2 = Path()..addRect(Rect.fromLTWH(10, 10, 100, 100));
    return Path.combine(
      PathOperation.difference,
      Path()..addRect(Offset.zero & size),
      path2,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Use of Clipper class in ClipPath,

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                ),
                Text(
                  '$_counter',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ClipPath(
            clipper: Clipper(),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black45,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

As output of above code there should be a while square hole of size 100 x 100 at coordinate (10,10). as defined in `path2` in `Clipper` class. but in web it is not working.

I tried different value of `path2` in `Clipper`. In some cases hole is visible but in other its not. I am adding some of those cases here,

```dart
final path2 = Path()..addRect(Rect.fromLTWH(10, 10, 100, 100)); // not working
final path2 = Path()..addRect(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 10, 100, 100)); // working
final path2 = Path()..addRect(Rect.fromLTWH(10, 120, 100, 100)); // not working
final path2 = Path()..addRect(Rect.fromLTWH(-10, 10, 100, 100)); // working
final path2 = Path()..addRect(Rect.fromLTWH(100, 10, 900, 1000)); // working
```

Please help me if anyone has a solution for this problem. If there is any other way to achieve same result as custom clipper that will also work.
In below link you can find an example for the same.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94212

Note: I am facing this issue only in web. for android, iOS and windows apps it is working fine. I'm using flutter 2.2.3.

Comment: @pskink thanks for comment. But as I mentioned in question it is working in some cases. Also, I am not getting any error while running application. that means Path.combine is implemented.

Comment: `@override
ui.Path getClip(ui.Size size) {
return Path()
..fillType = ui.PathFillType.evenOdd
..addRect(Offset.zero & size)
..addRect(Alignment.center.inscribe(size / 3, Offset.zero & size));
}`

Comment: thank you very much this partially solved my problem.

Comment: It is working. not just partially it completely solved my problem. Thanks again. and sorry for first comment.